# convert 'java.lang.String' to required type 'javax.servlet.http.Part'

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets, google-cloud-platform

I have a function `uploadFile()`.

```
public String uploadFile(Part filePart, final String bucketName) throws IOException {
  DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("-YYYY-MM-dd-HHmmssSSS");
  DateTime dt = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);
  String dtString = dt.toString(dtf);
  final String fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName() + dtString;

  // The InputStream is closed by default, so we don't need to close it here
  // Read InputStream into a ByteArrayOutputStream.
  InputStream is = filePart.getInputStream();
  ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  byte[] readBuf = new byte[4096];
  while (is.available() > 0) {
    int bytesRead = is.read(readBuf);
    os.write(readBuf, 0, bytesRead);
  }

  // Convert ByteArrayOutputStream into byte[]
  BlobInfo blobInfo =
      storage.create(
          BlobInfo
              .newBuilder(bucketName, fileName)
              // Modify access list to allow all users with link to read file
              .setAcl(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Acl.of(User.ofAllUsers(), Role.READER))))
              .build(),
          os.toByteArray());
  // return the public download link
  return blobInfo.getMediaLink();
}
```

I'm trying to call this function in another class called `uploadService.java`. How do I pass the argument as type `Part` in the following function?
 `uploadService.uploadFile();`

Comment: Why are you expecting a `Part` to begin with? I don't see anything in there that can't be changed to expecting a `String` for the file path (or even a `FileInputStream`) and a `String` for the file name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/blob/4f7072f0ea19d0bd7726544cabce0de10b373dda/bookshelf/3-binary-data/src/main/java/com/example/getstarted/util/CloudStorageHelper.java#L108

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: I'm currently having the value of ```filePart``` as String

Comment: So what exactly is the issue you are facing now since you are passing filePart as String ?